# MySQL IF . . . ELSE query syntax

Tags: mysql

I am struggling to find the correct syntax for IF / ELSE in a mysql query.
I know this can be done by defining a function or procedure but this then gets stored on the database, which I would need (at least for politeness) to get authorised by my DB manager.
For clarity this is the same as MS Sql allows with

```
IF @var=value
BEGIN
    @do=1;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   @do=2;
END
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

Comment: Removed the sql-server tag because the question is explicitly about MySQL.

Comment: Gordon,The question is comparing  what is accepted in mssql and mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF @var=value
 THEN
  SET  @do=1;
ELSE
  SET @do=2;
```

You are only missing the SET key word.

Comment: Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @var=value
 THEN
  SET  @do=1' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example of this syntax:

```
if _count = 0 then    
insert into A
else
    insert into B

end if;
```

Comment: Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if _count = 0 then    
insert into A